# Log axis2 client requests and responses

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I would like to log all requests/responses made by an axis2 client.
I tried to create a file called `client-config.wsdd` as describer in http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=15137 but without success (I don't get a log file).

Requests are made over https and I am not sure if it matters. I tried

```
<transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender"/>
```

and

```
<transport name="https" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender"/>
```

without success.

Comment: doesn't work for me too.
probably it was true to earlier versions (i.e. axis v1)

Comment: https://developervisits.wordpress.com/2017/06/20/apache-axis-logging-of-soap-requestresponse-programmatically/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For Axis2-client side logging for SOAP messages, just use the following JVM arguments while running your standalone client or include this VM args in your Appln. Server start script,

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=debug -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=debug
```

C:\java %JAVA_OPTS% YourClientAppln.java

Cheers,
Sankar

Comment: Sankar: The name of my hero today.

Comment: To run it in Eclipse, write those parameters in the Debug configurations/Run configurations in VM arguments

Comment: If you are already using log4j logger:

log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=debug
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=debug

Answer (score 4):

If you add the below lines to your log4j.properties file, you will need not to pass any VM or JVM parameters.

```
#Axis2
log4j.appender.AxisLogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AxisLogFile.File=${catalina.base}/logs/Axis-client.log
log4j.appender.AxisLogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AxisLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%X{UUID}] %5p %t %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=DEBUG,AxisLogFile
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit verbose, but here's how we solved it:

```
SOAPFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP12Factory();
OMElement requestElement = request.getOMElement(RegisterIntegrationAgent.MY_QNAME, factory);
LOGGER.debug(requestElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally just log the body of the SOAP message, passed to my service class.

```
public OMElement myOperation(OMElement request) throws AxisFault {

    log.debug("Request: {}", request);

    ..

    log.debug("Response: {}", response);

    return response
}
```

Low tech but works for me :-)

Comment: Thanks you I'm looking for client logging.

Comment: As mentioned by Manuel, this is applicable for the server side only

Answer (score 0):

-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=debug -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=debug

This worked

Comment: Duplicate of the 2 years old answer

Comment: Not quite.  It includes the httpclient.wire pattern, which logs the wire data.

Comment: @Scott: the pattern you speak of is included in the 2 (now 8) year old answer