# How to log request.xml and response.xml in Apache Axis2

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I am trying to log the request and response of a wsdl using Apache axis 2. I got some solution from internet of adding some SOAPHandler and add **client-config.wsdd** but i am not able to make it working at my place. Anybody can provide me a working solution or any reference which works actually.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this link is useful for you:
[Log axis2 client requests and responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524301/log-axis2-client-requests-and-responses)

Comment: No I want to store request and response xml in database.

Comment: https://developervisits.wordpress.com/2017/06/20/apache-axis-logging-of-soap-requestresponse-programmatically/

Answer (score 1):

In Axis2 exchanged messages are represented in `OperationContext`. So after the invocation of the service;

```
StringBuffer xmlRequestMessage = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer xmlResponseMessage = new StringBuffer();

OperationContext operationContext = stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext();
// For request message
MessageContext requestMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("Out");
xmlRequestMessage = new StringBuffer(requestMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString());
// For response message
MessageContext responseMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("In");
xmlResponseMessage = new StringBuffer(responseMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString());
```

Comment: This can't be done for ADB and XMLBeans data binding because IllegalOperationException occurs for the following reason:

https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5202